# How to fill 2d array with random numbers in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have a 2d array:

```
    val table: Array<Array<Int>> = Array(3) { Array(9) { 0 } }
```

How to populate it with random numbers from 1 to 90?

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Try _(1..90).random()_ instead of _0_

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are very close to the proper solution.

You are using "array with initializer" which allows you to initialize the Array while it's created.

```
Array(size) { index -> initializer }
```

Your call:

```
val table: Array<Array<Int>> = Array(3) { Array(9) { 0 } }
```

inits 2D Array with zeros.

So replace static `0` with a random number:

```
fun main() {
    val table: Array<Array<Int>> = Array(3) {
        Array(9) {
            (0..90).random()
        }
    }

    table.forEach { outer ->
        outer.forEach {
            print("$it ")
        }
        println()
    }
}
```

such a method prints (for example):

```
56 74 8 54 69 31 54 11 13 
12 8 45 8 47 61 55 89 58 
37 83 14 67 89 86 9 79 3
```

Comment: You should mention that this code will produce pseudo-random elements. So probably seeded random method should also be mentioned.

Comment: Can you explain what it means: outer ->
        outer.forEach

Comment: @Den the first call `table.forEach` iterates over elements. In each course, the element is assigned to "outer" variable. The name suggests it's the outer loop (as there is another one). You can read more here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html

Comment: @Steyrix it's not pseudo random. This extension method most probably uses timestamp as its seed (it's not specified in the docs). However, each run gives different results.

Comment: and what about consecutive numbers? how to fill it with them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
val table = Array(row) { IntArray(column) { (1..90).random() } }
```